# Area of intersection of 4 quadrants present in a square

Tags: geometry, area

If I were to draw 4 quadrants of circle inside a square, with each right angle being the angle between the arms of the quadrants, what will be the area of intersection.

Now I've tried this a few times and there's no way to find the area of the inner squarish figure which occurs twice in the intersection.

Finally, a preemptive apology, I am just a 15-year old who is a semi-Maths enthusiast who is unaware of proper terminologies.

The diagram (pardon, sire for 'tis drawn by me): https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzCrz.jpg

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977998/how-calculate-the-shaded-area-in-this-picture

Comment: @mathlove Yep. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do I close my question?

Comment: See my answer in https://www.facebook.com/Infopas-446849762154897/